# Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan when running Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Recently, when I tried to run `rails console` I have the error below.

I  installed the gems using `gem install` and configured the Gemfile correctly.
I tried to change the path by modifing .bashrc but nothing works.

```
[eduardo@arch server]$ rails c
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    bin/rails: Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan
    31: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in block in require'
    30: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in require'
    29: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    28: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in register'
    27: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    26: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in require'
    25: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in <main>'
    24: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in invoke'
    23: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:70:in find_by_namespace'
    22: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:39:in lookup'
    21: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:39:in each'
    20: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:40:in block in lookup'
    19: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:40:in each'
    18: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:44:in block (2 levels) in lookup'
    17: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in require'
    16: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in load_dependency'
    15: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in block in require'
    14: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in require'
    13: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    12: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in register'
    11: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    10: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in require'
    9: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:3:in <main>'
    8: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in require'
    7: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in load_dependency'
    6: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in block in require'
    5: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:26:in require'
    4: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in rescue in require'
    3: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    2: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in register'
    1: from /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    /home/eduardo/Projetos/rails/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in require': cannot load such file -- irb (LoadError)
```

My gem env:

```
[eduardo@arch ~]$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.0 (2019-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/eduardo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/eduardo/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/eduardo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/eduardo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/eduardo/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/eduardo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/eduardo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
     - /home/eduardo/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/eduardo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin
     - /home/eduardo/.rbenv/libexec
     - /home/eduardo/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/eduardo/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/eduardo/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin
     - /usr/bin/site_perl
     - /usr/bin/vendor_perl
     - /usr/bin/core_perl
     - /home/eduardo/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin`
```

Rails and Ruby version:

```
[eduardo@arch ~]$ rails -v
Rails 6.0.2.1
[eduardo@arch ~]$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: You tried to change the path of what?

Comment: Of the installation directory or at least tried.

Comment: Remove Ruby, remove rbenv, reinstall both, `bundle install`, then try again.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use proper grammar and spelling; "i" --> "I", "rails" --> "Rails", etc. SO isn't a message board or a forum, it's more like an online reference book where these things matter.

Comment: Could this currently open Github issue be related to your problem? https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/250